# Postgresql Import dump with user dfferent from postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

i'm tring to backup my database from production machine to a standby machine.

My production machine is a debian (unspecified version) distro

My standby machine is a ubuntu 20.10 distro

After some readings across the internet here is what i was able to accomplish

- pg_dump -h 123.123.123.123 -p 5432 my_db > my_db.bak -> check
- psql < createDateabase.sql -> check this make a simple drop/create database my_db owner my_db_backup;
- psql < my_db.back -> check

so far so good

- connect with my sqlworkbench to db -> check
- use table imported -> ehm, not check

the problem is the ownership of the tables and sequeces. When imported, postgres is their owner but i want my_db_backup as owner insted.

I have tryed, as a workaround, to

- alter table xxx OWNER TO my_db_backup; - > check for each table
- alter sequence if exists xxx OWNER TO my_db_backup; -> it takes forever and it is unable to finish;

the command for the final stage (change ownership) is
psql < finalize.sql

and finalize.sql is

```
\connect my_db;
ALTER TABLE xxx OWNER TO my_db_backup;
ALTER SEQUENCE IF EXISTS seq_xxx OWNER TO my_db_backup; -- this takes forever
```

what i'm missing?

I would prefer to import directly with the right owner instead of altering owner after, but that's still acceptable as long as i can change all objects in my_db

tnx for the help

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to change ownership of all the objects for the standby.  Why not keep it owned by the same owner?

Comment: @Jeremy well stand by is not totally standby :) the orginal user is busy with something else that don't need to see this database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to accomplish the import with a different user as follow

```
psql -U my_db_backup < my_db.bak
```

to avoid asking for password i had to make an entry in pg_hba.conf like this

```
local my_db    my_db_backup  trust
```

and to avoid request for password during the pg_dump i had to add this entry in my production machine

```
host  my_db  postgres     456.456.456.456/32    trust
```

where 456.456.456.456 id the ip of the standby machine.

i also had to change a bit the pg_dump to avoid errors for different user import

```
pg_dump -h 123.123.123.123 -p 5432 --no-owner --no-acl my_db > my_db.bak
```

so the complete script looks like

```
pg_dump -h 123.123.123.123 -p 5432 --no-owner --no-acl my_db > my_db.bak
psql < createDatabase.sql
psql -U my_db_backup < my_db.bak
```

EDIT: to make the script usable from any user there are a few things in need to be done

```
pg_dump -h 123.123.123.123 -p 5432 -U postgres --no-owner --no-acl -w my_db > my_db.bak
psql -U postgres < createDatabase.sql
psql -U my_db_backup < my_db.bak
```

Adding -U postgres is needed only because pg_dump try to login with the current user so if you are running the script as, for example, root pg_dump and psql will try to login as root and will obviously fail.

The other thing is the -w option that is needed to make pg_dump not ask for password.